# Remove a Column from result of query user /server in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Currently I am using this to show the remote sessions on our servers, but I would like to edit the resulting table to remove the column `SESSIONNAME`.

```
param([string]$Server)
query user /server:$Server
```

I have tried:

- a regular expression
- `format-table -property username,id,state,idletime,logontime`
- `Select` all the other columns.

All of these result in no output.

I tried the response from the post that has been linked here as a duplicate, but I believe it is not working because I have to fully qualify the server. I'm not sure how to tweak this code to show everything besides the sessionnames column.

```
param([string]$Input)

$Server = $Input + ".network"
$re = '(\w+)\s+?(\S*)\s+?(\d+)\s+Disc\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'

query user /server:$Server | Where-Object { $_ -match $re } | ForEach-Object 
{
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
    'Username'  = $matches[1]
    'SessionID' = $matches[3]
    'IdleTime'  = $matches[4]
    'LogonTime' = $matches[5]
  }
} | Select-Object Username, IdleTime
```

Comment: The last two fail because there are no "columns" to select from - the raw output from `query user` is just strings - you'll need to parse it yourself. Show us your regex attempt

Comment: `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), use something else for the variable name.